# PHP email from submit and stay on page

Tags: php, forms

Below is the code I'm using for my form. At the moment, when the form is submitted the message is shown on a separate page. I just want a message above the current form as appose to on a new page.

```
<div class="main_box">
<div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="clear"></div>

 <?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    <div class="main_col">
      <div class="main_col_left"><strong>BUSINESS NAME:</strong></div>
      <div class="main_col_right">
     <input type="text" name="business" id="business" value="" />
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="main_col">
      <div class="main_col_left"><strong>EMAIL ADDRESS:</strong></div>
      <div class="main_col_right">
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
      </div>
     </div>


     <div class="main_col">
      <div class="main_col_left"><strong>PROPERTY PURCHASE PRICE:</strong><span><strong>&pound;</strong></span></div>
      <div class="main_col_right">
     <input type="text" name="pur_price" id="pur_price" value="" />
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="main_col">
      <div class="main_col_left"><strong>REFURB COST:</strong><span><strong>&pound;</strong></span></div>
      <div class="main_col_right">
     <input type="text" name="refurb" id="refurb" value="" />
      </div>
     </div>


     <div class="main_col">
      <div class="main_col_left"><strong>Property Type :</strong></div>
      <div class="main_col_right">
      <select name="select2" id="select2" onchange="propType(this.value);">
          <option  value="">Select Property Type</option>
          <option value="0.3">Car Showroom</option>
          <option value="0.4">Care/Nursing Home</option>
          <option value="0.25">Dental Surgery</option>
          <option value="0.3">Department Store</option>
          <option value="0.3">Distribution Centre</option>
          <option value="0.3">FHL Apartment</option>
          <option value="0.3">FHL House</option>
          <option value="0.3">FHL Villa</option>
          <option value="0.3">Hotel/B&B </option>
          <option value="0.25">Industrial</option>
          <option value="0.3">Industrial with Office</option>
          <option value="0.3">Medical Centre</option>
          <option value="0.25">Multi-Storey Car Park</option>
          <option value="0.35">Nursery</option>
          <option value="0.25">Office</option>
          <option value="0.25">Office with Residential</option>
          <option value="0.3">Petrol Station</option>
          <option value="0.3">Public House</option>
          <option value="0.3">Research Facility</option>
          <option value="0.3">Restaurant</option>
          <option value="0.25">Retail Warehouse</option>
          <option value="0.3">Retail Shop</option>
          <option value="0.3">Retail Shop & Office</option>
          <option value="0.3">Shopping Centre</option>
          <option value="0.3">Sports Centres</option>
          <option value="0.3">Students Residence</option>
          <option value="0.3">Theatre</option>
          <option value="0.3">OTHER</option>
        </select>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="main_col" style="display:none">
      <div class="main_col_left"><strong>AVERAGE CLAIM RATE :</strong><span><strong>&pound;</strong></span></div>
      <div class="main_col_right">
     <input type="text" name="avg_claim_rate" id="avg_claim_rate" value="" />
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="main_col">
      <div class="main_col_left"><strong>AMOUNT CLAIMABLE :</strong><span><strong>&pound;</strong></span></div>
      <div class="main_col_right">
     <input type="text" name="amount_claim" id="amount_claim" value="" />
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="main_col">
      <div class="main_col_left"><strong> YOUR TAX RATE :</strong></div>
      <div class="main_col_right">
       <select name="tax_rate" id="tax_rate">
       <option value=".24">24%</option>
       <option value=".4">40%</option>
      </select>
      </div>
     </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <hr />
 <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="main_col">
    <div class="main_col_left"><strong>CLIENT TAX BENEFIT :</strong><span><strong>&pound;</strong></span></div>
    <div class="main_col_right"><input type="text" name="client_benefit" id="client_benefit" value="" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main_col">
    <div class="main_col_left"><strong>INSTANT CASH RECLAIM:</strong><span><strong>&pound;</strong></span></div>
    <div class="main_col_right"><input type="text" name="cash_reclaim" id="cash_reclaim" value="" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main_col">
    <div class="main_col_left"><strong>FUTURE TAX RELIEF :</strong><span><strong>&pound;</strong></span></div>
    <div class="main_col_right"><!--<span id="future_tax_rel"></span>--> <input type="text" name="future_tax_rel" id="future_tax_rel" value="" /></div>
    </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
   <hr />
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p style="line-height:20px;">Note : These figures are estimates and the final figures may very depending upon the property and full circusstances</p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="main_col">
    <div class="main_col_left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="main_col_right">
    <button onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button>

    </div>
   </div>

   </form>
   <?php 
    }  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
    { 
    $name=$_REQUEST['business']; 
    $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
    $pur_price=$_REQUEST['pur_price']; 
    $refurb=$_REQUEST['refurb']; 
    $select2=$_REQUEST['select2']; 
    $select=$_REQUEST['select']; 




    if (($name=="")||($email=="")) 
        { 
        echo "Please enter business name & email"; 
        } 
    else{         
        $from="Business : $name\r\nEmail : $email\r\nPurchase Price : $pur_price\r\nRefurb Cost : $refurb"; 
        $subject="CTA Associates Calculator "; 
        mail("test@test.com", $subject, $from);
        } 
    }   
?> 
<button onclick="reset();">Reset</button>
  <div class="clear"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You have two options: redirect the user to the same page and render a message somewhere next to the form. Or, use javascript to submit the form using an xhr request (ajax) and let the user stay on the page. The second option is the best in terms of UX, a little bit more difficult though. But our friend google should help you out with this.

Comment: and don't use the multipart type if you're not submitting files. Not necessary at all
And remove your e-mailaddress from the code (unless you want everyone to send you a birthday card ;))

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['status']))
        echo "success";
?>
```

end in the end of your code add header('Location:page.php?status')

Comment: The header redirect won't work in case of succes since something would have been echoed before.

Comment: if everythink is good hi can add an echo after function mail without use a variable $_GET